# sql: selecting specific data concerning two different tables

Tags: sql, oracle

So here's the situation, I made two tables:

table 1:

```
create table Show (
    id number(5),
    moderator_id number(5),
    length number(3),      
    title varchar(100),
    details varchar(30)
);
```

table 2:

```
create table Moderator (
    id number(5),
    name varchar(30),
    surname varchar(30)
);
```

The two tables are in relation: 1(Moderator), N(Show) 
I need a command, that displays name and surname of moderator, that haves the biggest SUM of length (Show.length represents length of individual show).

Comment: what is your idea ? how would you make this possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it...

```
select * from (select name,surname from moderator 
   inner join show on moderator_id = moderator.id
   group by  moderator.id,name,surname
   order by sum(length) desc) 
where rownum = 1
```

**Edit:** Tested in sqlfiddle using sample data -   http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1a264/10/0

Comment: Your GROUP BY isn't discriminating enough; you have to do it by a unique identifier. Otherwise, if I add another person with the same name I can break your model: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4c9ac/1

Comment: Thanks @Ben   I've added moderator.id to the group by clause.